# ionic2/angular 2 - *ngfor not working on map markers content

Tags: angular, google-maps, ngfor

I am trying to print data on my map marker's infowindow. I manage get the data in the `console` but unable to print on the infowindow. The marker and infowindow did appear on the map, except fail to retrieve the data.

The code is for testing purpose, so I only get one object from the JSON Object array.

I did a test for `*ngfor let listing of maps.data` on the `maps.html` the data did appeared.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance :)

**function to get location and display marker stored in googlemaps provider**

```
initMap(): Promise<any> {

this.mapInitialised = true;

return new Promise((resolve) => {

  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

    // fixed position
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.352100, 103.819800);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
      position: this.map.getCenter(),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

     let mapListings = this.load();
     let data = this.mapListings;
     console.log(this.data[0]);


     let content = '<ion-item *ngFor="let listing of this.data[0]">' + 
     '<h2 class="payment_color">{{ listing.ListingTitle }}</h2>' + 
     '<p>{{ listing.ListingDatePosted }}</p>' +
     '<p>{{ listing.ListingDescription }}</p>' +
     '</ion-item>';          

     this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

    resolve(true);


  });

});
```

}

**console.log(mapListings) output**

```
t {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: Array(4)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: Array(4)
__proto__: Object
```

**console.log(this.data[0]) output**

```
Object {ListingTitle: "This is the Title", 
ListingDatePosted: "20-July-2017", 
ListingDescription: "Hello World"}
```

**Output on Infowindow**

```
{{ listing.ListingTitle }}
{{ listing.ListingDatePosted }}
{{ listing.ListingDescription }}
```

[image: Output on Infowindow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using another approach and it works. Not sure why *NgFor not working.

```
for ( let listing of this.data){
 let content = '<ion-item>' + 
     '<h2 style="color:red;">' + listing.ListingTitle +'</h2>' + 
     '<p>' + listing.ListingDatePosted + '</p>' +
     '<p>' + listing.ListingSalary + '</p>' +
     '</ion-item>';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. Replace the let content with the following code

```
let content = `<ion-item *ngFor="let listing of this.data[0]">
     <h2 class="payment_color">{{ listing.ListingTitle }}</h2>
     <p>{{ listing.ListingDatePosted }}</p>
     <p>{{ listing.ListingDescription }}</p>
     </ion-item>`;
```

keep the above code, then in your provider or wherever you are calling initMap(), try this.

```
import { NgZone  } from '@angular/core';

    constructor(public zone: NgZone) {
    }

     this.zone.run(() => {
     initMap();

  });
```

Comment: Yes. It still return {{listing,ListingTitle}}. I tried ` '<h2 style="color:red;">{{ listing.ListingTitle }}</h2>'`. The styling works but the data is not coming up

Comment: where are you calling initMap()? Can you wrap the call to initMap in a ngZone?

Comment: the initMap() is calling from a provider.